# How to display ratio members in a non-measure dimension (accounts) in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, olap, iccube

Using the pivot table in Excel with an OLAP Server (icCube), I would like to add financial logic.
The logic is not in the measures as I would like to apply the logic to multiple measures (e.g. amount, last_year_amount, budget etc).

I would like to add the logic to the Accounts dimension. In icCube see 2 ways to do this:

1. make use of a specific facts aggregation (Unary Operator) (see http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/facts_aggregation.php). The logic here is limited to +, -, divide and multiply, and this is too limited for my formulas.
2. create calculated members in the Accounts dimension.

I have choosen for option 2. This works perfectly, except for the fact that these are not displayed in the Excel add in (the functions children() and members() do not work on calculated items).

This is illustrated in the enclosed picture below.

How can I achieve calculated members in the Accounts hierarchy which are displayed in Excel using the Excel add in?

[image: Explanation of the question using the Excel Analysis Services plugin on icCube]

Note that these calculated items exist. They are just not displayed. How can I achieve that these are also displayed, so a user can select these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of icCube are you using?

We've found a regression with calculated "measures" being not displayed; but calc. "members" seem properly displayed in a pivot table and within the dimension selectors (right part in Excel).

What kind of object in Excel is the "[+] Ratios" ?

[edit: by the way if a member contains calc-member(s) only, depending on where it is used, Excel might not display them as most of the time AddCalculatedMembers() is being used (this function is adding "sibbling" as calc. members).]

Comment: version  4.8.2 06-Jan-2015 08:51:20 GMT

Comment: Ratios is also a calculated member (create member [Rubriek].[Rubriek].[Ratios] as null).
The members are created in the MDX IDE at runtime.

Comment: There seems to be an issue when the calculated member is created within the " all " level (that is the root level containing the all member). Excel does not display it as the request sent is drilldown into the ' all ' member. As a workaround you can create the [Ratios] within the all member instead.